# USART2 Rx not working, Bluepill / STM32F103C8T6

Tags: stm32, uart

I'm using Libopencm3, USART1 and USART3 are working fine, but the USART2 makes problems.

I can send bytes, when i get one, the IRQ handler function is called, but using usart_recv() i get nothing, do i need to do more configuration for using USART2?

TX = PA2

RX = PA3

Here my code:

````
void usart2_isr (void)  {
    static char data = 1;

    /* Check if we were called because of RXNE. */
    if (((USART_CR1(USART2) & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != 0) &&
        ((USART_SR(USART2) & USART_SR_RXNE) != 0)) {
        
        /* Retrieve the data from the peripheral. */
        data = usart_recv(USART2);
        // ECHO
        usart_send(USART2, data);
    }
}

void UART2::setup() {
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_AFIO);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART2);

    /* Enable the USART2 interrupt. */
    nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_USART2_IRQ);

    gpio_primary_remap(
        AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG_JTAG_OFF_SW_ON,
        0);

    gpio_set_mode(GPIOA,
    GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50_MHZ,
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_PUSHPULL,
    GPIO_USART2_TX);

    gpio_set_mode(GPIOA, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_CNF_INPUT_FLOAT, GPIO_USART2_RX);

    usart_set_baudrate(USART2,9600);
    usart_set_databits(USART2,8);
    usart_set_stopbits(USART2,USART_STOPBITS_1);
    usart_set_mode(USART2,USART_MODE_TX_RX);
    usart_set_parity(USART2, USART_PARITY_NONE);
    usart_set_flow_control(USART2, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
    usart_enable(USART2);

    USART_CR1(USART2) |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;
    usart_enable_rx_interrupt(USART2);
}
```
````

Comment: Is this more or less the only code? No other peripherals used? There are know conflicts between USART2 and SPI1 (see errata). The last two lines do the same thing. No problem though. "...but using usart_recv() i get nothing": it always returns a byte. So does it return 0 or isn't it called at all?

Comment: Its only this code, usart_recv returns 0 byte, it should have the value sended via usb tty, with USART 1 und 3 works without problems. Can i excplicit deactivate SPI?

Comment: If SPI clock isn't enabled, it should be disabled.

Comment: The MCU has the marking " 991KA 93 MYS 807" it seems to be counterfeit, i bought it on amazon, i will try to get a genuine chip to solder or board and will report if it works. Maybe i update the arm, gcc toolchain to the latest version.

Comment: ST has confirmed that all chips with "991KA 93 MYS 807" are counterfeit. So it's counterfeit indeed.

Comment: I ordered STM32F103CBT6 has more flash and is on stock, i will try to desolder it with hotair or vaccum station, i hope e get it out without damaging the pcb, I will report, dont know why they sell this fake boards and not use genuine parts, it doesnt cost more....